# Error when changing a post privacy with the Facebook PHP SDK

Tags: php, facebook-php-sdk

What I'm doing is creating a post with the Facebook PHP SDK(v4)(and the app is set to use the v2.3 API) with the privacy settings of value to SELF, then later on changing the value to CUSTOM, and allow to the ids of the friends that have accepted the app.

Until recently everything worked fine, and now out of the blue I'm getting this error(nothing changed on our part): "(#100) Object does not support message editing", which I couldn't locate in their documentation. Has anybody encountered this situation and this error?

Here is the code I'm using (like I said everything worked fine until recently)(if you need more details please let me know)

```
        $fb_token = 'FB_TOKEN';

        $FB_session = new FacebookSession($fb_token);
        try {
          $FB_session->validate();
        } catch (FacebookRequestException $ex) {
          // Session not valid, Graph API returned an exception with the reason.
          //echo $ex->getMessage();
          throw new RestException(501,'FB error: '. $ex->getMessage());
        } catch (\Exception $ex) {
          // Graph API returned info, but it may mismatch the current app or have expired.
          //echo $ex->getMessage();
          throw new RestException(501,'FB error: '. $ex->getMessage());
        }

        //make posting request to FB
        if($FB_session) {
          try {
            $fb_array = array(
                'privacy' => array(
                                'value' => 'CUSTOM',
                                'allow' => 'USER_ID'
                                )
              );

            $fb_req = new FacebookRequest(              
              $FB_session, 'POST', "/POST_ID", $fb_array
            );
            $response = $fb_req->execute()->getGraphObject();
            //echo "Posted with id: " . $response->getProperty('id');
            $fb_post_id = $response->getProperty('id');             

          } catch(FacebookRequestException $e) {
            //echo "Exception occured, code: " . $e->getCode();
            //echo " with message: " . $e->getMessage();
            throw new RestException(501,'FB error: '. $e->getCode() .'-'. $e->getMessage());
          }   
        }
```

Comment: Has anything changed between it working and not working? Updated any libraries or anything like that?

Comment: Hello, no, nothing changed on our part. I suspect Facebook changed something, but they did not reply to my questions yet. Like I said I can't track down that error message either, to see what it is related to exactly.

Comment: Ahh okay. That could be worth maybe just adding to the post that nothings changed on your end. I haven't used the SDK myself but this does seem like it's something on Facebook's end that's causing issues. Have you tried looking through the stacktrace of the error and seeing where it started?

Comment: It is happening when trying to change the privacy of the post, when trying to execute the facebook request: $fb_req->execute() , and the error is a response from the facebook server